# Deploy Custom Permission via Apex

Tags: custom-permission

I am facing this when implementing a custom permission xml, but when deploying, the status is success, but it is empty, no element is deployed.

```
public without sharing class CustomPermissionController {
 @InvocableMethod(label='Criar Permissão Personalizada')
 public static void create(List<Request> props) {
    String xmlContent =
            '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n' +
            '<CustomPermission xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">\n' +
            '    <isLicensed>false</isLicensed>\n' +
            '    <label>' + props[0].customPermissionName + '</label>\n' +
            '</CustomPermission>';

    String packageXml = 
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'+
    '<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">'+
    '    <types>' +
    '        <members>' + props[0].customPermissionName + '</members>'+
    '        <name>CustomPermission</name>'+
    '    </types>'+
    '    <version>59.0</version>'+
    '</Package>';
    String fileName = props[0].customPermissionName.replace(' ', '_').toLowerCase() + '.customPermission-meta.xml';
    Zippex zippex = new Zippex();

    Blob xmlBlob = Blob.valueOf(xmlContent);
    zippex.addFile('customPermissions/' + fileName , xmlBlob, null); 

    Blob packageBlob = Blob.valueOf(packageXml);
    zippex.addFile('package.xml', packageBlob, null);

    Blob zipData = zippex.getZipArchive();
    String zipEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(zipData);
    String res = deployZipByRest(zipEncoded);
    System.debug('response '+res);
}
public static String deployZipByRest(String zipEncoded) {
    String crlf = '\n';
    String boundary = '--------------------------BOUNDARY';
    String endPoint = URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v43.0/metadata/deployRequest';
    System.debug('endPoint ==>:'+ endPoint);
    
    Map<String, Boolean> deployOptions = new Map<String, Boolean>();
    deployOptions.put('rollbackOnError', false);
    deployOptions.put('singlePackage', true);
    
    String deploymentOptions =  '{"deployOptions" :{"allowMissingFiles" : false,"autoUpdatePackage" : false,"checkOnly" : false,"ignoreWarnings" : false, "performRetrieve" : false,"purgeOnDelete" : false,"rollbackOnError" : false, "runTests" : null, "singlePackage" : false,"testLevel" : "NoTestRun"}}';
    Blob body = getBinaryPostBody(crlf, boundary, deploymentOptions, zipEncoded);

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint(endPoint);
    req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
    req.setBodyAsBlob(body);
    req.setTimeout(100000);
    req.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueof(req.getBodyAsBlob().size()));       

    Http http = new Http();
    HttpResponse res = http.send(req);
    System.debug('status code ==>: ' + res.getStatusCode());
    System.debug('response body ==>: ' + res.getStatus());
    String response = res.getBody();
    return response;
}
public static Blob getBinaryPostBody(String crlf, String boundary, String deploymentOptions, String bodyEncoded) {
    String header = '--' + boundary + crlf
            + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="entity_content"' + crlf
            + 'Content-Type: application/json;'  + crlf + crlf
            + deploymentOptions + crlf
            +'--' + boundary + crlf
            + 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="deploy.zip"' + crlf+
            + 'Content-Type: application/zip;' + crlf + crlf;
    String footer = + crlf + '--' + boundary + '--';
   
    String headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header));
    while(headerEncoded.endsWith('=')){
        header += ' ';
        headerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(header));
    }

    System.debug('bodyEncoded==>'+bodyEncoded);
    String footerEncoded = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(footer));

    Blob bodyBlob = null;
    String last4Bytes = bodyEncoded.substring(bodyEncoded.length() - 4, bodyEncoded.length());
    if(last4Bytes.endsWith('=')){
        System.debug('last4Bytes==>'+last4Bytes);
        Blob decoded4Bytes = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(last4Bytes);
        HttpRequest tmp = new HttpRequest();
        tmp.setBodyAsBlob(decoded4Bytes);
        String last4BytesFooter = tmp.getBody() + footer;  
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded + bodyEncoded.substring(0, bodyEncoded.length() - 4) + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(Blob.valueOf(last4BytesFooter)));
    }
    else{
        bodyBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);
        System.debug(headerEncoded + bodyEncoded + footerEncoded);
    }
    return bodyBlob;
 }

public class Request {
    @InvocableVariable(label='Name' required=true)
    public String customPermissionName;
}
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you deploy via hand-written XML that corresponds to this Apex? Please edit your question and show that.

Comment: When I deploy via vscode, it works.

Comment: Any idea? @identigral